# nodejs + mongodb - find empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to find all rows where post_id is the same as I'm searching for. But every time I do the result is empty, and I've double check all values and I should get some result.

This is the method I'm using:

```
db.collection('posts', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({}, {}, {limit:100}).toArray(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) res.send({'error':1,'message':'error getting all posts'});
        console.log('Number of posts: ' + posts.length);
        posts.forEach(function(entry) {
            db.collection('love', function(err, collection) {
                collection.find({}, function(err, love) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    if (!love) console.log("empty");
                    if (love) {
                        console.log(love);
                        entry.love = love;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        res.send(JSON.stringify(posts));
    });
});
```

It always enter the third if like if I have a result but in the console I always get [] from the result. Any idea of that I'm doing wrong?

EDIT1: Code updated.

Comment: What happens if you try to console.log(love); with no JSON?

Comment: @Zorba it gives exactly the same result: []

Comment: Hmm, the only other thing that I think could be wrong is that your find criteria is not working well... Maybe for debugging try changing to collection.find({} ..., so it returns all documents and you can check if the id really matches?

Comment: Could you post the code fragment that shows how entry is created? and the entry._id value is set?

Comment: @Zorba I tried and got some result.

Comment: @Saintedlama Updated the code with the full code.

Comment: This might seem a bit silly, but are you 100% sure that your love collection is not actually empty? If possible check it directly with mongo client. If it isn't then I'm all out of ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `love` in that callback is a cursor, not the array of docs.  To make it an array, call `toArray` like you are in your first query; like this:

```
collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, love) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (!love) console.log("empty");
    if (love) {
        console.log(love);
        entry.love = love;
    }
});
```

Also, your next problem will likely be that your `res.send` call won't include any of the `love` docs because it's happening before any of the `love` callbacks.  You need to delay calling `res.send` until all callbacks have been received.  You can do that by keeping a count of outstanding callbacks or using an async flow control module like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: thanks, I was wondering why res.send was executed before the rest. But I dont understand why that is executed before all the stuff that is before it in the function?

Comment: @just_user It's because the `db.collection` and `collection.find` calls are asynchronous; meaning the calls return immediately, and their callbacks aren't called until later.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. But I'm not sure how to do an async call for two queries. I mean, I need the posts query to be able to do the love query. How do I put that in an async task?

Comment: it's "weird", when you `console.log(love)`, it displays `[]`, but a conditional for `if (love === [])` doesn't catch it. `console.log(typeof(love))` also displays `object` (when it is seemingly an `array`). the `if (!love)` conditional is not catching an empty result for me either. the only conditional that worked for me was `if (love.length === 0)`.